# Not able to entirely scrape HTML table using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, xml-parsing, rvest

I've used the following R script:

```
url="http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/253802.html?class=3;orderby=default;template=results;type=batting"
check=readHTMLTable(url,header = T)
check$"Career summary"
check<-check$"Career summary"
```

I'm only able to scrape first 11 observations.

Can anyone suggest why i'm unable to scrape entire table?

Comment: There are more than one tables on that page. Inspect the page in your browser. I think you are only getting the contents of the first `<tbody>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the content of all tables on the page:

```
library(XML)

url="http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/253802.html?class=3;orderby=default;template=results;type=batting"

content <- htmlParse(url)

tbody <- xpathSApply(content, "//tbody")

lapply(tbody, function(x) readHTMLTable(x, header=T))
```

Answer (score 0):

AS @Wietze314 said there are more than one table on that page.
You can get a list of all the table I suppose you are interested in with:

```
url="http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/253802.html?class=3;
orderby=default;template=results;type=batting"

check=htmlParse(url)    

tableNodes <- getNodeSet(check, '//tbody')
tbList <- lapply(tableNodes, readHTMLTable)
```

`tbList` contains 22 data.frames for you to work with

Comment: Thanx @Gamba it did solve my problem. Can you please tell what is table Nodes here!?